# How can I vectorize Floyd-Steinberg's Dithering algorithm with numpy?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, opencv

I've used Floyd-Steinberg's dithering algorithm to reduce an image to a combination of 6 colours. From the pseudocode on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering), I've been able to implement the algorithm with NumPy.

I'd love to speed up the algorithm and I'd like assistance in vectorizing my implementation. Here's my original implementation here:

```
def findClosestColour(pixel):
    colors = np.array([[255, 255, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 0, 255], [255, 255, 0], [0, 128, 0], [253, 134, 18]])
    distances = np.sum(np.abs(pixel[:, np.newaxis].T - colors), axis=1)
    shortest = np.argmin(distances)
    closest_color = colors[shortest]
    return closest_color

def floydDither(img_array):
    height, width, _ = img_array.shape
    for y in range(0, height-1):
        for x in range(1, width-1):
            old_pixel = img_array[y, x, :]
            new_pixel = findClosestColour(old_pixel)
            img_array[y, x, :] = new_pixel
            quant_error = new_pixel - old_pixel
            img_array[y, x+1, :] =  img_array[y, x+1, :] + quant_error * 7/16
            img_array[y+1, x-1, :] =  img_array[y+1, x-1, :] + quant_error * 3/16
            img_array[y+1, x, :] =  img_array[y+1, x, :] + quant_error * 5/16
            img_array[y+1, x+1, :] =  img_array[y+1, x+1, :] + quant_error * 1/16
    return img_array
```

Now here's my attempt at vectorizing some portions of the algorithm:

```
def closestColour(img_array):
    colors = np.array([[255, 255, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 0, 255], [255, 255, 0], [0, 128, 0], [253, 134, 18]])
    distances = np.sum(np.abs(img_array[..., np.newaxis] - colors.T), axis=2)
    nearest_colors = np.argmin(distances, axis=2)
    quantized = colors[nearest_colors]
    return quantized

def floydDitherVec(img_array):
    new_img = closestColour(img_array)
    error = img_array - new_img
    height, width, _ = new_img.shape

    for y in range(0, height-1):
        for x in range(1, width-1):
            new_img[x+1, y, :] = new_img[x+1, y, :] + (error[x+1, y, :] * 7/16)
            new_img[x-1, y+1, :] = new_img[x-1, y+1, :] + (error[x-1, y+1, :] * 3/16)
            new_img[x, y+1, :] = new_img[x, y+1, :] + (error[x, y+1, :] * 5/16)
            new_img[x+1, y+1, :] = new_img[x+1, y+1, :] + (error[x+1, y+1, :] * 1/16)

    return new_img
```

Finally, I'm making use of `openCV` to read images and process them like so:

```
image = cv2.imread('test2.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

My overall goal is to make the algorithm run faster and any means of achieving this goal is welcome.

Comment: I think I'd try that with `numba`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to speed up the algorithm using [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/). The implementation is given below:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def floydDitherspeed(img_array):
    height, width, _ = img_array.shape
    colors = np.array([[255, 255, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 0, 255], [255, 255, 0], [0, 128, 0], [253, 134, 18]])
    for y in range(0, height-1):
        for x in range(1, width-1):
            old_pixel = img_array[y, x, :]
            max_distance = 195075
            for color in colors:
                p_distances = old_pixel - color
                p_distances = np.power(p_distances, 2)
                distance = p_distances[0] + p_distances[1] + p_distances[2]
                if distance <= max_distance:
                    max_distance = distance
                    new_pixel = color
            img_array[y, x, :] = new_pixel
            quant_error = new_pixel - old_pixel
            img_array[y, x+1, :] =  img_array[y, x+1, :] + quant_error * 7/16
            img_array[y+1, x-1, :] =  img_array[y+1, x-1, :] + quant_error * 3/16
            img_array[y+1, x, :] =  img_array[y+1, x, :] + quant_error * 5/16
            img_array[y+1, x+1, :] =  img_array[y+1, x+1, :] + quant_error * 1/16
    return img_array
```

In comparison with the `floydDither` function, the `numba` implementation runs approximately 5x faster.